# Construct an NFA over alphabet {, } that accepts all words with more a’s modulo 4 than b’s modulo 3.

Tags: automata

Construct an NFA over alphabet {, } that accepts all words with more a’s
modulo 4 than b’s modulo 3. For example, “” is accepted as it has two
a’s and one b. The word “” is accepted as it has six a’s and four
b’s.

I must be missing something obvious, as any solution I come up with gets increasingly messy.

I would love to hear anyone else's solutions.

Comment: NFA means non finite automata?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want I have an answer: think of circulating matrices

Comment: Is it strict inequalities or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I build an automata which end states accepted are colored in red and to avoid confusion, I pointed the initial state; here is the link for the [quiver diagram](https://q.uiver.app/#q=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)

**I forgot to color $(2,2)$ in red! and the above $b$ is in fact an $a$**

Here is a screenshot of the diagram:
[image: automata]

Comment: well damn, that's 100 times better than what I was doing haha. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can accept the answer or upvote it if you think you can have better (but it seems it is the simplest possible)